# grep or splice on large array

Tags: perl

I have a large array of hashes, about 0.5Gb, stored in memory, and I need to remove some elements from it, about 10% spread around the whole array.

What is likelier to work best, doing a grep, or identifying the elements that need deleting, and splice-ing them out?

Thanks,

Simone

Comment: the memory used doesn't matter; how many elements in the array does

Comment: Please take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415287/how-can-i-delete-an-element-of-a-referenced-array/4415420#4415420), it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`splice` may go to O(n^2) under conditions you describe (as it moves array content around), and `grep`/slice would allocate O(n) extra memory (probably, much less than 500GB, but still...).

There is a linear solution with no extra memory though, but looks more like C than like Perl:

```
sub inplace_grep {
    my ($code, $array) = @_; 
    # move elements backwards
    for (my ($to, $from)=(0,0); $from < @$array; $from++) {
        $code->($array->[$from]) or next;
        $array->[$to++] = $array->[$from];
    };
    # remove tail 
    splice @$array, $to; 
};
```

**Update:** on grep memory usage -- you can do a quick test  for extra memory allocation by using large amounts of data and looking for `brk` syscall. On my system (linux, perl 5.10) it does.

```
strace -e trace=brk perl -MTime::HiRes -wle \
'print "start ".time; my @array = 1..10**7; print "alloc ".time;
@array = grep { $_ %2 } @array; print "grep ".time'
```

Answer (score 5):

Benchmark it?  I would guess, not knowing what your data really looks like, that grep would be faster than multiple calls to splice for an array with a lot of elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you know which elements you want to **keep**, then you can just index them with an array slice:

```
@want = @all[ @wanted ];
```

or

```
@all = @all[ @wanted ];
```

As to which of `grep` and splice is fastest, `splice` will be quickest, as all it needs to do is shift some pointers around in C, and delete the things you no longer keep from memory, `grep` will need to a bit more work as it requires a call to your selection function for every member of the original list.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know which elements you are interested in removing that it will be by definition faster as you won't have to search form them, only remove them. Otherwise, `grep` is your best bet for a fast filtering method.